# WPA3 with Freeradius and SAMBA AD DC

Tags: samba, freeradius

I have a working Freeradius authenticating WiFi users (windows,mac,linux,ios,android) with WPA2 enterprise using samba AD DC for user directory.

I want to move to WPA3 Enterprise but I am not sure if this can be done at all.

I am trying to figure out if it is theoretically possible to support WPA3 enterprise with Freeradius and Samba AD DC to authenticate clients with username/password from AD?